# Azure - Firebase Remote Config Equivalent

Tags: azure, firebase, azure-mobile-services, firebase-remote-config

Are there any features available in Azure that is equivalent to Firebase Remote Config which allows roll out of features to a mobile app without a republish?

I have looked at the Azure mobile and other services offered in Azure. But, nothing seems to provide a similar functionality.

Comment: By any chance, were you able to find an answer to this?  I am also looking for something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Going around Azure, I found something that seems to be still in preview but could be what you were looking for, and it's called Azure App Configuration.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-configuration/

Here is a super lovely blog post too.

https://adrianhall.github.io/android/2019/09/22/azure-app-config/

I hope this helps you. :)